# Can Entity Framework context be passed as a variable?

Tags: entity-framework-6

My context.SaveChanges() contains over 60 lines of error handling catching exceptions such as DbUpdateException or DBEntityValidationException, etc. It is tedious to duplicate that error handling in every SaveChanges throughout my various solutions. Is there some way to pass the context as a variable type to a single library routine? For example

```
public bool mySaveChanges(*Entities* anyDbContext)
{
    anyDbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

where the type 'Entities' would be replaced with some language construct meaning any Entities and not a specific Entities.edmx.

P.S. Yes, I am aware that EF is not thread safe but there is only one user running this code so not concerned about that aspect.